# Jackson: Is there a way to exclude everything by default in a class and include explicitly?

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, deserialization

I have been messing about with Jackson for a while now and can't for the life of me figure out how to make Jackson only include the properties I tell it to.

We have a setup with datamodels that inherit from a base class and we would like to exclude everything from this base class by default, perhaps with a few exceptions.

Because of this, it would make a lot more sense for us to be able to exclude everything unless it's explicitly included.

Why is this not possible? It seems like a very common use-case to me.
I couldn't find anything that even resembled a solution after hours of googling and trial and error

What I would like to end up with is something like this:

```
@JsonIgnore
public class BaseClass {
    @JsonInclude
    private long usefulProperty1;

    @JsonInclude
    private BigDecimal usefulProperty2;

    @JsonInclude
    private BigDecimal usefulProperty3;

    private int garbageProperty;
    //.
    //.
    //.
    private int garbageProperty200;
}

public class SubClass extends BaseClass {
    private String usefulProperty1;
    private long usefulProperty2;
}
```

That is, I'd like to only use annotations, or at the very least, a one time implementation in the base class. I don't want extra boilerplate code in every class that tells Jackson what to include/exclude.
Also, we don't really care about getters and setters (we just specify the fields and have Lombok generate getters and setters), so it would be nice with a solution where we can apply annotations directly to the fields.

I tried visibility options but that just resulted in the class not being serialized/deserialized at all.
I feel like I've tried every combination of @JsonInclude @JsonProperty @JsonIncludeProperties (on class) @JsonIgnore and the likes, and nothing worked for me.

Comment: Have you tried [`@JsonView`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.9.1/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonView.html)?

Comment: I hadn't tried that but from what I can see, it requires some boilerplate to be able to use @JsonView. Also, I don't quite see how it would help me to exclude everything by default and explicitly mark the properties I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of these solutions:

1. First solution

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"usefulProperty2", "usefulProperty3"}, ignoreUnknown = true)
public class BaseClass {
    private long usefulProperty1;
    private BigDecimal usefulProperty2;
    private BigDecimal usefulProperty3;
    private int garbageProperty;
    // other properties
}
```

2. Second Solution

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class BaseClass {

    @JsonIgnore
    private long usefulProperty1;

    @JsonIgnore
    private BigDecimal usefulProperty2;

    @JsonProperty
    private BigDecimal usefulProperty3;

    @JsonProperty
    private int garbageProperty;

    // other properties
}
```

3. Third Solution: You can use **Mixin** is a class containing the fields you want to include with **@JsonInclude** annotations. This mixin will be used to configure the serialization of BaseClass

```
public class Mixin {
    @JsonInclude
    private long usefulProperty1;

    @JsonInclude
    private BigDecimal usefulProperty2;

    @JsonInclude
    private BigDecimal usefulProperty3;
}

public class BaseClass {
    private long usefulProperty1;
    private BigDecimal usefulProperty2;
    private BigDecimal usefulProperty3;
    private int garbageProperty;
    // other properties
}


public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.addMixIn(BaseClass.class, Mixin.class);

        BaseClass baseClass = new BaseClass();
        baseClass.setUsefulProperty1(1000);
        baseClass.setUsefulProperty2(BigDecimal.valueOf(42.000075));

        String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(baseClass);
        System.out.println(json);
    }
}
```

Try it and let me know

Comment: Both of your solutions unfortunately requires me to explicitly ignore, but what I actually want is ignore by default. Since there are many properties I don't want included, it is not feasible to manually exclude them.

Comment: i updated the the post, check the third solution and i hope this solution help you